# Footprints for SMD electrolytic capacitors

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, altium, footprint, electrolytic-capacitor

Does Altium Designer Summer 09 has footprints for SMD electrolytic capacitors? If so, where can I find them?

[image: SMD electrolytic cap]

I've noticed the dimensions of these type of capacitors are given in *diameter x height*. How can I find out the dimensions of the pads, provided I don't have the datasheets for the capacitors?

Is there a standard for the SMD electrolytic capacitors' footprints?

Comment: You shouldn't use parts for which you can't get datasheets.

Comment: @stevenvh ARGH! Ask me about it! In Turkey, we have electronics part suppliers that give only the inductance of an SMT, SMPS inductor! No, datasheet, even no parameters! You have to buy a sample, measure and create a footprint.. How sad..

Comment: @abdullah - Can't you buy from Digikey, for instance? They have datasheets for 99.99 % of their parts.

Comment: @stevenvh Yeah, Digi-Key ships to Turkey, however it is going to be VERY expensive. I don't think it is different to Romania either.. Come be an electronics designer in Turkey, you will love it :)

Comment: @abdullah - Hey, nobody asked you to become an engineer! ;-) You can always open a döner kebab restaurant. No more worries about datasheets! :-)

Comment: @stevenvh haha! I love eating döner kebab, but man, cooking it, in this hot weather, in front of that cooker? No way!

Comment: @abdullah - What hot weather? Only 18°C here in Belgium, we haven't seen much summer yet this year :-(

Comment: @stevenvh That's good advice, but sometimes it just so happens that I'm using a part that doesn't have a datasheet. You mentioned Digikey, but they have high shipping costs because they ship the components from USA (am I wrong?). But I'm aware there are suppliers in Europe too. I usually use Farnell and TME. But sometimes I just need a single component and I'll buy it over the counter from a local shop in town. Most of the times I can't find datasheets for such components.

Comment: @stevenvh: hah! you think that the kebab rolls have a datasheet? No way, you have to understand how to slice them by yourself!

Comment: Focus, guys! :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right, m.Alin gets a notification each time. Sorry m.Alin!

Answer (score 7):

Here are land pattern details for those capacitors:

https://web.archive.org/web/20131102032848/http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ABA0000/ABA0000PE251.pdf

Comment: Can you bring over information so that it is not just a PDF, although a footprint lookup is a pretty localized question...

Comment: @Kortuk I assume there are standard footprints for _all SMD electrolytic capacitors_. IMO, it's not a localized question at all.

Comment: @m.Alin, May be the case, this is still a link only answer that needs to be expanded. Your question was not for general footprints for SMD, it was for this specific chip.

Comment: Leon, the link has perished, unfortunately.  Could you fix it please?

Comment: It's still there!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which library Altuim keeps the SMD electrolytic capacitors, but I suggest you get a copy of [Mentor Graphics LP-Viewer](http://www.mentor.com/products/pcb-system-design/library-tools/lp-wizard/lp-viewer-download) (the free edition) which contains a fairly comprehensive set of footprints for most component types.

The parts contained in this software comform to the latest IPC recommendations for manufacturability.  For most uses select the "N" (nominal) footprints library, aluminium electrolytic parts should be available under the name "CAPAE" followed by the base body size X height (as per the [IPC7351B](http://landpatterns.ipc.org/IPC-7351BNamingConvention.pdf) naming convention).

Answer (score 2):

Q: Does Altium Designer Summer 09 has footprints for SMD electrolytic capacitors?

A: No , Altium 09 does not carry standard footprints for capacitors.  Subsequent versions of Altium have [Altium Vault service](http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/Vault-Driven+Electronics+Design).

Advice: Most designers have to make their own footprints in Altium.  For a capacitor with a clear footprint diagram in the datasheet, it will take less than 15 minutes to create a footprint.  If you need more information on how to make custom footprints, I suggest reading a [post about creating a footprint](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/create-altium-footprint-from-scratch-for-molex-connector).

Comment: Thanks, lyncas. For this particular instance I wanted to use some capacitors that didn't have any datasheet (Yes, I know! It's a bad practice. Still..). The only dimensions I had available were the diameter x height. I was wondering if there's a standard footprint for SMD electrolytic capacitors based on those dimensions, so that I wouldn't need to make a footprint for every similar capacitor I use. As for the post you linked, you can see that I familiar with it. I've previously edited the post & added some useful links in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a standard JEDEC footprint that would be suitable enough for that part, and Altium has PCB footprint distributions that should contain what you need:

http://www.altium.com/community/libraries/altium-designer-libraries/altium-designer-footprint-libraries/en/altium-designer-footprint-libraries_home.cfm

You will want to analyze the prototypes to ensure you have a good solder joint with an appropriate amount of solder and fillet and tweak the footprint for that part accordingly.  Keep in mind that even with datsheets, slightly different solder formulations, slightly different process temperatures and stages, etc will all affect the solder joint, and for the best reliability you will end up customizing all your pads to their individual parts based on your analysis of the resulting joint.

The datasheets and JEDEC guidelines are just that - guidelines.  Don't assume that just because you have a compatible footprint that your joint is reliable and strong.